# git command equivalent to p4 sync -n

Tags: git

Before I pull from a remote repository I would like to size up the changes. Not completely sure what information is available. A list of commits (with descriptions) and a list of files changed is a good place to start.

For anybody familiar with perforce, I want the exact equivant to "p4 sync -n".

I thought this would be easy. I first checked "git help pull". I then checked google. Run out of places to check.

Comment: Not sure what “size up the changes“ means exactly, but maybe you’re looking for `git fetch` followed by `git diff HEAD...@{u}`? Or `git pull --dry-run`?

Comment: I am not seeing dry-run in "git help pull".

Comment: On the surface, git-fetch seems to be way off the mark. Since the meaning isn't clear, where would I find documentation that applies get-fetch to my use case?

Comment: What is @{u}? I am not finding that in "git help diff".

Comment: @tdprime I have edited my answer to address your comment.

Comment: The answer to your question is _"**Do not** use `git pull`"_. It is not good for what you need, it is not good for almost anything except creating surprises. Run `git fetch` then use `git log` to find the differences. Or, better, use a Git GUI application to inspect for the changes.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct equivalence for [`p4 sync -n`](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_sync.html) in Git.

- You cannot [directly determine the size of the next fetch (part of a git pull)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50669168/6309)
- You can try and look at the prefetch namespace ([`git fetch --prefetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---prefetch)), [introduced with Git 2.32](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67351884/6309), but that might not include size information.

> A list of commits (with descriptions) and a list of files changed is a good place to start.

That would still involve a `git fetch` first.
Then, as commented:

```
git diff --name-only @ @{u}
git log --pretty=oneline @{u}..HEAD
```

As illustrated in "[How to compare a local Git branch with its remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37848701/6309)", `@{u}` from [git revisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltbranchnamegtupstreamemegemmasterupstreamememuem)

> The suffix `@{upstream}` to a branchname (short form `<branchname>@{u}`) refers to the branch that the branch specified by branchname is set to build on top of (configured with `branch.<name>.remote` and `branch.<name>.merge`).